# Can I omit "is" in the following way of presenting list items?

Tags: ellipsis, lists, gapping

> The first item I drop into my shopping basket is a mayonnaise tuna
>   rice ball. The second (is) a cup of instant noodles. The third (is) a
>   can of dry beer.

Can I drop the two last isses? Why or why not?

Comment: As a learner: Yes you can, it's called ellipsis. You can check the tag ellipsis for more info. However, I am not sure about your punctuations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't drop the auxiliary verb ***unless*** you are speaking too informally! In other words, you can omit them while speaking; they are called *ellipsis.* Ellipsis are the words *dropped* from a sentence because without them, the *meaning is understood.*

If you are *writing* those sentences formally, certainly, you don't drop any of those. In addition, a semicolon goes better in such structure:

> *The first item I drop into my shopping basket is a mayonnaise tuna rice ball; the second (is) a cup of instant noodles; the third (is) a can of dry beer.*

Comment: Actually, gapping often appears in formal writing: *Some of the immigrants went to small farms in the Midwest; others, to large Eastern cities.*

Comment: Or "The first item I drop into my shopping basket is a mayonnaise tuna rice ball, the second a cup of instant noodles, and the third a can of dry beer."